# How to check if array size has changed using while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

How do I check if the array size has increased or values of the array have been changed.

```
while(ARRAY.array_size_changed || ARRAY.array_altered==true) {
    System.out.println("Array size increased or decreased or values changed");
    //rest of the code is here which alter the array size
}
```

I have used `boolean` but it makes the code loop forever.

Basically, I have an array which keeps track of any result from a database and adds it to ARRAY. based on the new values entered into ARRAY the next iteration will perform. when there is no further addition to ARRAY or change in values it will exit.

Comment: Just set both booleans to false after you handle the case if it is true.

Comment: How are `array_size_changed` and `array_altered` populated? Some more context would be useful.

Comment: `== true` can be omitted. If you want to be explicit about it (which is fine), you should however do it in both cases. Your code is inconsistent in style.

Comment: i have added some more details which can be of help. but is there any method which can check an array for changes?

Comment: There is no such method. However if you only need to be notified about added or removed elements, save the original length in a variable and use `int originalLength = array.length; while (originalLength == array.length) {...}`. To detect value changes however, you need to keep track of changes manually, either by creating your own data structure for it, or setting flags whenever you modify any value.

Comment: can you explain more, is this `ARRAY` declared app-scope? are there more than a thread working with this array? like if this array could be altered in some other place than where the while loop exists?

Comment: This array has to work as a working memory of a rule base system in expert system. so this is the main part where it has to match rule with the facts in the wm. and if matches found update the working memory(array here). so when i dont get any match then array will remain same as in its previous iteration so it will exit.

Comment: I think you don't need while block, you need a when method to wrap your array operations so when method fired you can handle your processes.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut can you explain a little bit? I need the code to be repeatedly executed as far as array is altered in any way.

Comment: I mean, do your array operations in a method you can create your own class to do this operations so you can handle array changes(add, remove, reverse etc.). This is just an simple idea , if you need an exact code example about my opinions , i prepare.

Answer (score 1):

I would add some data abstraction and only allow those values in your array to be changed / added through a changed method or add method. This way when this method is called, you know that something is about to be added / changed.